# Multiple driver error for SystemVerilog initial value

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In my code I have an `always_comb` block coded as follows:

```
always_comb
begin
    if ( x == 0 )
        z = some_value ;
    else if ( y == 1 )
        z = some_different_value ; 
end
```

some_value and some_different_value.
`z` is defined and given an initial value ( for simulation purposes ) as follows:

```
logic z = 42 ;
```

When I compile - I get an error: **"Multiple drivers to always_comb output variable z detected"**.
Is it a bug in the tool?

Comment: Do you want to make an unclocked latch? AFAIK that's generally a bad practice - all registers (latches) should act on clock edges.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get rid of the `end` before the `else`. The compiler is confused about where the first `if` ends.

Also,

- `always_comb` doesn't allow outside processes to write left-hand side variables (vs. `always @ *`, which does)
- regardless, more than one driver the same `wire` type is not allowed. The `always_comb` boils down to an assignment for `z`, so trying to `assign` it again outside results in the multi-driver error.

More about all that here: https://www.verilogpro.com/systemverilog-always_comb-always_ff/

And here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101717/difference-among-always-ff-always-comb-always-latch-and-always

Finally, if your intention is for `z` to have some default value, careful coding style would include it in the body of the if-else statement as the final `else`. This is clearer for someone else reading your code (or yourself, later.)

Comment: The 'end' is a typo (fixed it). 
What if I want to avoid X's in simulation for the value of z ?

In VHDL for example - I know it's perfectly legal to initialize combinatorial logic in such a way...

Comment: For simulation, variables that get updated by multiple statements would be the ‘reg’ type. These would be part of a whole procedural block that contains the test vector set. ‘wire’ variables (either explicit or implicit) can have one and only one ‘assign’.

Comment: Suppose (for some reason) you want to synthesize a latch (not a dff).
And in simulation - you want this latch to have an initial value of 0. 
How would you code it ?

Comment: Like any sequential element, if I care about its state at startup I code it with a reset.

Comment: @shaiko also check this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/550509/238188

Comment: That said, in most designs very few flops actually need to have a known initial state (generally, counters and FSMs). As someone else said, ‘X’ is your friend - watching how these propagate gives deep insight into your design and how to make it more robust. Your goal should be for your logic to recover from an unanticipated state on its own.

Answer (score 5):

You can write a statement inside the combinational block like this:

```
always_comb
begin
   z = 42; 
   if ( x == 0 )
        z = some_value ;
    else if ( y == 1 )
        z = some_different_value ; 
end
```

This statement before the if statement executes if none of the statements in the if statement are true. It is an alternative method of writing this:

```
always_comb
begin
    if ( x == 0 )
        z = some_value ;
    else if ( y == 1 )
        z = some_different_value ; 
    else
        z = 42;
end
```

If you write statements in both the else block and before the if condition statement, then the value assigned in the else block will be reflected and the other value will be ignored.

#### Note: Ensure all possible conditions are covered in the if statement for combinational logic!

**If you really need a latch use `always_latch`, not `always_comb`!**

---

Regarding the concern of avoiding Xs in simulation, the best option is to declare the datatype as `bit` instead of `logic`. Doing so will initialise it to 0 since `bit` is 2-state.

Note: While 2-state simulation is faster, it is not recommended since it can cover up failure to initialise the hardware at start-up.

Comment: X is your friend! Don’t avoid or suppress it, fix the bugs where they occur.

Comment: @Michael I agree.

Comment: So the bottom line is: "Verilog/Systemverilog simulation tools don't support default assignments for combinatorial logic ?" Correct ?

Comment: @shaiko, you can use default statements in the else part of the if statement or as per the other code... It's not the tools but the language that stops you from assigning multiple drivers to a single logic datatype