# Designing a jk flip-flop that has a toggle state when j=k=0

Tags: flipflop

Can we design a JK flip-flop using only NOR gates? The logic circuit implementation would look like this.

[image]

In this case the toggle state would be when j=k=0 instead of when they're equal to 1.

Comment: There probably are others but, LTspice has its A devices which have up to 5 inputs (unused ones can be left unconnected, they are discarded). So you can easily test that. Be sure to add `td=<...>` (`td` means "time delay") to avoid race conditions. You can read up more on them in the manual (`F1`) under *LTspice > Circuit Elements > A. ...*.

Answer (score 2):

Despite circuits resembling yours being ubiquitous in the internet, the circuit actually has serious problems is unreliable. (An example of the broken NAND version, for example can be found [at this site](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/sequential/seq_2.html)

The basic problem with your circuit, and the NAND version is that it is a *latch* with feedback, and neither a master-slave flip-flop, nor an edge triggered flip-flop. As a result, when feedback is enabled by setting the J and K inputs appropriately, it is not guaranteed that that the circuit won't oscillate during a clock pulse, nor is it guaranteed that the circuit will actually change state.

Here is an implementation of your circuit in CircuitLab

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv6fQG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

As you can see, it oscillates, rather than toggles on clock pulses.

To see toggle flip-flops that actually work, see [this question and its answers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/540518/268467). If you swapped the nand gates for nor gates in either a Master-Slave JK flip-flop, or a *true* edge triggered flip-flop, you will, if you do it right, get a genuine flip-flop that toggles when J=K=0.