# How to complete the truth table for a JK flip flop? And why?

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

I saw this question, but am unsure how to solve it. I have tried various approaches and get some of the answers correct, but never all of them...so my method is obviously wrong

[image]

For example, what should the 3rd inputs be for the 3-input NAND gates? Should it be the current initial Q & 'Q...or should it be the Q and 'Q from the 'final' columns in the previous row? Likewise, what should the 2nd the Q & 'Q inputs to the 2nd NAND gates be? No matter which method I try, I can't get all the answers correct

Answer (score 1):

Let's take your 6th line as an example: `J = 1, K = 0, Clk = 1, Q = 0, ¬Q = 1`. This is saying that the flip-flop is currently unset (`Q=0`), and that we want to set it (`J=1`).

If you follow it through in a single-pass then you get:

```
J = 1
K = 0
Clk = 1
Q = 0
¬Q = 1

:.

Top gate     = ¬(¬Q ^ J ^ Clk)
             = ¬(1 ^ 1 ^ 1)  
             = ¬1 
             = 0
Bottom gate  = ¬(Q ^ K ^ Clk)
             = ¬(0 ^ 0 ^ 1) 
             = ¬0 
             = 1
output Q'    = ¬(TOP ^ ¬Q)  
             = ¬(0 ^ 1) 
             = 1
output ¬Q'   = ¬(BOT ^ Q)
             = ¬(1 ^ 0)
             = 1
```

Which is "incorrect" according to every JK truth table out there, because `J=1, K=0` should be a 'set' operation, but here we have both Q being not set and unset at the same time, which makes no sense.

Another way of thinking about it is that the right hand side is a NAND latch, and we know that in a NAND latch if the top (¬set) line is 0 and the bottom (¬reset) line is 1 then it *should* be Q = 1. But we don't see that. There is a lot of stuff online and in books explaining how that a NAND latch works, so I won't repeat, but the key takeaway is that the truth table is a bit of a lie as almost every explanation requires a bit of feedback to take place during the "calculation", as *the truth table being derived from the observed results* rather than the other way around.

And the problem here is that you're trying to derive the behaviour from the truth table!.

So if we take the situation we just calculated and let that "run" for a few more evaluations, we see that:

```
output Q2    = ¬(TOP ^ ¬Q')  
             = ¬(0 ^ 1)    # This input has not changed
             = 1
output ¬Q2   = ¬(BOT ^ Q')
             = ¬(1 ^ 1)    # This input HAS changed
             = 0
```

Which gets the result we want! What happens if we run it a third time?

```
output Q3    = ¬(TOP ^ ¬Q2)  
             = ¬(0 ^ 0)    # This input HAS changed
             = 1           # But the output hasn't
output ¬Q3   = ¬(BOT ^ Q2)
             = ¬(1 ^ 1)    # This input has not changed
             = 0
```

A fourth round of evaluation?

```
output Q4    = ¬(TOP ^ ¬Q3)  
             = ¬(0 ^ 0)    # No change
             = 1            
output ¬Q4   = ¬(BOT ^ Q3)
             = ¬(1 ^ 1)    # No change
             = 0
```

Thus it is now "stable".

The setup-and-hold times of the physical flip-flops will have this oscillation/race-condition taken into account, and the actual amount of wall-clock time it'll take to stabilise depends on all of the gate's [propagation delay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_propagation_delay). However it's all abstracted away in the truth-table (and the gates themselves are an abstraction of underlying analogue circuits). And that's also the main reason we use a clock to synchronous our these kinds of circuits: The output of the flip-flop is not "valid" until a few gate-delays have happened and the result is stable.

---

If you look on [falstad](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-nandff.html) at an NAND latch you can see this behaviour.

And turn the simulation speed down to lowest and have fun toggling between set and reset (press the H under set and reset). Note that in your 6th line it will be reset, so reset it and then pay attention to what happens when you press set. First both Q and Qbar are HIGH. Then that feedsback and it settles on Q=1 ¬Q=0.

See [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/491352/jk-latch-possible-ben-eater-error/491439#491439) which also talks about oscillations, though that's talking about the AND-NOR case, which will oscillation in different configurations.